# When to use frame decoding

Tags: netty

It is not clear to me, if I need to use a frame decoder like LineBasedFrameDecoder when building a custom POJO decoder based on the MessageToMessageDecoder?

It states in the Netty source code of the StringDecoder, that a [frame decoder must be used together with the StringDecoder](https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4f78bae2eb756ccd95e879c9d049ba56046ab90e/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/string/StringDecoder.java#L31).

I guess yes, buy why?

Answer (score 0):

I ask myself if this should be an answer or not; You could use what ever implementation you want. The JavaDocs are providing a sample of how you should encode/decode data for the strings. You could implement your own handlers and determining the string start and stops.

For example I implement my own packet protocol which mixes a lot of data for a online video game. So I decode my strings by just reading a varint and then the string. I could take this same logic and create my own handler for decoding the string lengths before the StringDecoder Handler.

**Encoder**

```
public static ByteBuf encodeString(ByteBuf out, String value, Charset charset) {
    byte[] bytes = value.getBytes(charset);
    encodeArray(out, bytes);
    return out;
}

public static ByteBuf encodeArray(ByteBuf out, byte[] bytes) {
    int length = bytes.length;
    encodeInteger(out, length);
    out.writeBytes(bytes);
    return out;
}

public static ByteBuf encodeInteger(ByteBuf out, int number) {
    return encodeInt(out, number, computeUInt32Size(number));
}

public static ByteBuf encodeInt(ByteBuf out, int number, int numBytes) {
    int originalIndex = out.writerIndex();
    int adjustedI = originalIndex + numBytes;
    final int capacity = out.capacity();
    if (adjustedI > capacity) {
        out.capacity(adjustedI);
    }
    out.writerIndex(out.writerIndex() + numBytes);
    for (int i = adjustedI - 1; i >= originalIndex; i--) {
        int curByte = (number & 0x7F);
        if (i != (adjustedI - 1)) {
            curByte |= 0x80;
        }
        out.setByte(i, curByte);
        number >>>= 7;
    }
    return out;
}

public static int computeUInt32Size(int value) {
    if ((value & (~0 <<  7)) == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    if ((value & (~0 << 14)) == 0) {
        return 2;
    }
    if ((value & (~0 << 21)) == 0) {
        return 3;
    }
    if ((value & (~0 << 28)) == 0) {
        return 4;
    }
    return 5;
}
```

**Decoder**

```
public static String unsafeDecodeString(ByteBuf in, Charset standardCharsets) {
    byte[] bytes = unsafeDecodeArray(in);
    return new String(bytes, standardCharsets);
}

public static byte[] unsafeDecodeArray(ByteBuf in) {
    int len = unsafeDecodeInteger(in);
    return unsafeDecodeArray(in, len);
}

public static byte[] unsafeDecodeArray(ByteBuf in, int len) {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    in.readBytes(bytes, 0, len);
    return bytes;
}

// This is unsafe as we do not check readable bytes, is safe if apart of a packet read all at // once
 public static int unsafeDecodeInteger(ByteBuf in) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; i++) {
        int curByte = in.readByte();
        n = (n << 7) | (curByte & 0x7f);
        if ((curByte & 0x80) == 0) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was a weird question sparked by a comment in the Netty source code.

To answer my own question: *It depends!*
If you do not have a fixed length data frame, then you need some way for both client and server to agree on when a data frame is at the end – complete. It could be as simple as a \r \n (carriage return + newline) or another agreed upon char(s).